# Public open Wifi connection does not pop up portal log in

Tags: wireless

A particular Public open Wifi connection does not open (any) browser pop-up (captive) portal to allow log in.

Question:

Is there  a way to manually force the log in?

My Ubuntu version is 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

Answer (score 1):

If you can identify the gateway IP address you should be able to open any browser and enter that address to be redirected to the page generally brought up in the pop-up. One way to get the gateway IP is by bringing up a terminal and typing `ip route list` which should give you output something like this:

```
default via 10.140.128.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600
10.140.128.0/18 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.140.140.111 metric 600
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000
```

The IP address listed just after `default via` should be the gateway ip address. This has worked for me in the past but I haven't tested recently.